# Given $A$, $B$ and $C=(I+AB)^{-1}$ find $(I-BCA)(I+BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

All matrices are square and $(I+AB)$ is invertible.
Part B of the exercise is to prove that $(I+BA)$ is invertible.

Quite frankly I have no idea how to do this, I've tried rearanging the matrices but it didn;t help.
I've read about the Woodbury matrix identity but it doesn't seem helpful.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}(I-BCA)(I+BA)&=I-BCA+BA-BCABA\\&=I-BCA+BA-BC((AB+I)-I)A\\&=I-BCA+BA-BA+BCA=I\end{align}

Comment: You look good in a top hat! +1

Answer (score 2):

Try the distributive property of matrix multiplication:
$$(I - B \, C \, A) \, ( I + B \, A ) = I - B \, C \, A + B \, A - B \, C \, A \, B \, A$$
Now, group the second and forth term.